# Default value not respected with Entity Framework Core Insert

Tags: entity-framework-core

My SQL Server 2017 table is created in Transact-SQL as follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JobTag]
(
    [JobId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Comment] [nvarchar](2048) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_JobTag_1] 
       PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([JobId] ASC, [Name] ASC)
                   WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                         IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JobTag] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_JobTag_Created] DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [Created]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JobTag]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_JobTag_job] 
        FOREIGN KEY([JobId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[job] ([JobID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[JobTag] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_JobTag_job]
GO
```

For the model I include

```
 public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
```

In .Net Core, when I try to add a record using

```
   var newTag = new JobTag { JobId = job.JobID, Name = "myName", Value = myValueString};
   connect.JobTags.Add(newTag)
   connect.SaveChanges()
```

I get an error

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException:
>   An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The conversion of a datetime2 data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

I do not get an error if I initialise the `Created` property with `DateTime.Now`.

If I remove the property from the model, then the SQL Server DateTime is used correctly.

Why do I need to initialize the property when it has a default value?

Comment: Use Fluent API configuration and it will generate the appropriate default constrain for the auto generate date-time

Comment: One simple solution is use `datetime2`  instead of `datetime` for `Created` column

Comment: @TanvirArjel  will that make use of the datetime from the database?  The c# code is running on a different pc.

Comment: It will generate appropriate `datetime` for `Created` column during insert in database. You don't need to assign it manually in c# code.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values

Comment: Yes it is: `modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Property(b => b.Created).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null values can be stopped, or allowed, in either place, but the database has the final say.

In your model, it should be DateTime.Now for the default date.

**If you did want to allow nulls**

Putting DateTime? for the column type in model may fix the issue. This will allow the value to be null from the application perspective, which probably occurs before the record is created in the database.

```
public DateTime? Created { get;set;}
```

**If you do not want to allow nulls and want the flexibility of not identifying a value when creating a new record from the application**

set it to a default value in your model:

```
public DateTime Created { get;set;}=DateTime.Now
```

**The problem is**

In your database, you say it is required:

```
[Created] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

But, in app, you don’t set it.

```
var newTag = new JobTag { JobId = job.JobID,     Name = "myName", Value = myValueString};  
connect.JobTags.Add(newTag)
connect.SaveChanges()
```

The problem is two fold, as by setting:

```
public DateTime Created { get;set;}
```

You are also saying it is required from the application perspective, as it does not include the ?, meaning no nulls are allowed, but it has no default value.

The requirement needs to match in both places.

Comment: Surely  public DateTime Created { get;set;}=DateTime.Now  in the model does not have the same effect as using getdate() in the fluent api ?

Comment: In summary I need to either declare the fluent api properties or not have the datetime in the model.